# Removing character from a list of words

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I have a list of strings like below.

```
arr = ['U.S.A','Ph.D','Mr.']
```

I would like to clean this array of the period so that the output would be like

```
arr = ['USA','PhD','Mr']
```

Is there a clean regex way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use `map`, a higher order function which allows you to control the mapping of array elements to a new array, which allows you to control how each element should be converted `new_arr = list(map(lambda str: str.replace('.', ''), arr))`

Answer (score 2):

If it's just dots, you don't need a regex:

```
[x.replace('.', '') for x in arr]
```